# Solving vector equation 3

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

> Solve for $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$
>   $$\bar{x}+\bar{y}=\bar{a},~~ \bar{x}\times \bar{y}=\bar{b},~~ \bar{x}.\bar{a}=1$$

Attempt:

$\bar{x}+\bar{y}=\bar{a}$ dot by $\bar{a}$, we get $1+\bar{a}.\bar{y}=|\bar{a}|^2$ i.e $\bar{a}.\bar{y}=|\bar{a}|^2-1$

$\bar{x}\times \bar{y}=\bar{b}$ pre-cross by $\bar{a}$, we get $$(\bar{a}.\bar{y})\bar{x}-(\bar{a}.\bar{x})\bar{y}=\bar{a}\times \bar{b}\implies (|\bar{a}|^2-1)\bar{x}-\bar{y}=\bar{a}\times \bar{b}$$

I need another such equation to solve $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate $y$ by substituting the first equation into the second
$$\eqalign{
  y &= a-x \cr
  b &= x\times y &= x\times(a-x) &= x\times a \cr\cr
}$$
Now we need to isolate $x$, so let's cross the last equation by $a$
$$\eqalign{
  a\times b &= a\times(x\times a) \cr
 &= a^2x-(a\cdot x)a \cr
 &= a^2x-a \cr
}$$
Now you can solve for $x$ entirely in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Then you can substitute that result to solve for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

You found one equation and use second equation which is given $i.e.$

$x+y=a$ . Use these two equations to find $x$ and $y$

Hope this will be helpful !